# Does physical aerobic exercise ameliorate depression?

Tags: depression

Studies seem to find correlation, but has the causal link been established?

Comment: Exercise ameliorates depression, a natural endorphin release approx 20 mins into the routine.

Comment: Yes, depressed people tend not to exercise enough to feel good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different theories about the causes of depression. Three of them assume a cause that could be affected by aerobic exercise.

**Neurochemical theory of depression:**

It seems that depression might be caused by low serotonin and/or noradrenalin levels. Physical activity releases both neurotransmitters, thus alleviating depressive symptoms.

**Cognitive theory of depression:**

It seems that negative cognitive schemata cause depression. Sports improves self-efficacy and other schemata.

**Diathesis–stress model of depression:**

Depression is the result of a predispositional vulnerability combined with stress from adverse life experiences. Aerobic exercise relaxes the sympathetic nervous system thus alleviating stress and, as a consequence, depression.

Maybe someone else will come up with studies showing a causal connection. These (and other) theories might explain the connection.

Comment: Over 3000! do we have a party :)